# Setting the JPanel pixel size then fitting it inside a JFrame

Tags: java

I know that the `JFrame` pixel size includes the title bar, and the sides, so I want to create a panel instead, and use the `pack()` method to fit the panel inside the `JFrame`. The problem is, whenever I run the code, the window shows up at size 0 for some reason, despite the `JPanel` being some other size. Here's my code.

```
    /*This part of the code is from one class.*/
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    P.g.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.getContentPane().add(P.g);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}


/*This part of the code is from another class.*/
public class P extends JPanel {

static P g = new P();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawLine(100, 0, 100, 300);
    g.drawLine(200, 0, 200, 300);
    g.drawLine(300, 0, 300, 300);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, because the effective size of your JPanel is 0,0. Override `getPreferredSize()` in P to return the required size, and pack should result in the correct result (dependant on your layoutmanager).

```
/*This part of the code is from another class.*/
public class P extends JPanel {
     static P g = new P();

     @Override
     public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
         return new Dimension(requiredWidth , requiredHeight);
     }

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);

         g.drawLine(100, 0, 100, 300);
         g.drawLine(200, 0, 200, 300);
         g.drawLine(300, 0, 300, 300);
    }
```

}
`

Comment: Can you show me exactly where to put the getPreferredSize() method? Please?

Comment: i've edited the post. the getPreferredSize is now implemented apart from the values

Comment: Thank you so much! So the override method is built in, and it basically set the panel size right? Since we can't set the panel size when we're extending it?

Comment: no, it doesn't **set** the size, it only returns the size of the area a component needs to display correctly. to set the actual size of a component, you have to use setSize(), but this interface is also used by frame.pack() and layoutmangers to set the size, so this value will change/be ignored

Comment: `Can you show me exactly where to put the getPreferredSize() method?` Seriously??? You have been given this information several times over the last 3-4 days. Several times you have been asked to read the Swing tutorial on `Custom Painting`. The tutorial contains working examples, which you were asked to use as a starting point. You have been asked NOT to use static variables. You have been asked to use meaningful class names. Yet you continue to waste peoples time!!!